# Solve for a Specificed Variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following literal equation that needs to be solved for h:

$$S= \pi r \sqrt{r^2+h^2} $$

I isolated the square root and got this:

$$\frac{S}{ \pi r} = \sqrt{r^2+h^2}$$

Then I squared both sides to eliminate the square root on the right:

$$\frac{S^2}{ \pi^2 r^2} =r^2+h^2$$

Then I isolated the h term:

$$\frac{S^2}{ \pi^2 r^2} - r^2 =h^2$$

Now I am not quite sure what to do.  I assume that it is more complex than just square rooting everything to get:

$$\frac{S}{ \pi r} -r=h$$

An algebraic calculator says the solution is:

$$h= \frac{ \sqrt{- \pi^2r^4+S^2} }{ \pi r} and \; h= -\frac{ \sqrt{- \pi^2r^4+S^2} }{ \pi r}$$

But I don't understand how it computed that solution.  Could anyone give me a step-by-step explanation of your solution?

Comment: It should be $h=\pm \sqrt{\frac{S^2}{\pi^2 r^2}-r^2}$

Comment: @Alex It's the same thing after putting everything with the same denominator.

Comment: @Git Gud Yes, but that's where he made the mistake.

Comment: @ProfessorStealth You're making two mistakes. One is assuming that $x^2=a\implies x=\sqrt a$. Correct would be $x^2=a\implies x=\pm \sqrt a$. The other is that $\sqrt{x+y}\neq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S= \pi r \sqrt{r^2+h^2} $$
$$\frac{S}{\pi r}=\sqrt{r^2+h^2} $$
$$\frac{S^2}{(\pi r)^2}=r^2+h^2 $$
$$\frac{S^2}{(\pi r)^2}-r^2=h^2 $$
$$h=\pm\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{(\pi r)^2}-r^2}$$
$$h=\pm\sqrt{\frac{S^2-(\pi r)^2r^2}{(\pi r)^2}}$$
$$h=\pm\frac{\sqrt{S^2-\pi^2 r^4}}{\pi r}$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution.  But how would I go about giving $r^2$ a common denominator with the other terms?  Also, would this be necessary or just additional work?